# Is it possible to create Realm class without default values for parameters?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I understand that this is not possible with Kotlin because Realm needs an empty constructor.

However, this creates an issue that we may accidentally create a RealmObject without setting all the required fields. Hence, the purpose of required fields is lost.

I was wondering if someone has found a way around this Realm limitation.

Comment: The purpose is not lost since you would still get an error upon saving this empty RealmObject. Add custom constructors, validate the data before saving and don't make "accidents" in your code :p